# Passive mode for vsftpd without SSL inside a VM

Tags: virtual-machine, ftp, ssl, ubuntu-16.04, vsftpd

this is my scenario: someone needs to push some files from a really old mainframe that only works with plain FTP (no SSH, no SSL). In my environment, I have a VM with Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-139-generic x86_64) image, where I set up a vsftpd server. The VM has public address `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.` However, the internal addresses are different:

```
$ ifconfig   
ens3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:aa  
          inet addr:YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY  Bcast:YYY.YYY.YYY.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: aaaa::aaaa:aaaa:aaaa:aaaa/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1450  Metric:1
          RX packets:676755 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:244476 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:712807318 (712.8 MB)  TX bytes:20949942 (20.9 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:355 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:355 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:23535 (23.5 KB)  TX bytes:23535 (23.5 KB)
```

I have no external control of this VM. I request it on a system, and it gives me an IP address, user, and password. God knows where this VM is.

So, I have the following configuration for vsftpd:

```
listen_address=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX. # External IP here.
pasv_address=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.   # External IP here too.
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=NO
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

Using this configuration, I can access the server remotely and push files without a problem. Note that the IPs on the configuration file (`XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX`) are the external IP, not the internal one (`YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY`).

However, as the title suggests, my partner cannot use SSL connections. Since vsftpd does not accept user/password plain authentication when SSL is enabled, I have to turn that off:

```
ssl_enable=NO
```

But now, I have a lot of problems. This is an example when I try to connect to the server:

```
$ ftp XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Connected to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX).
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
Name (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:alice): bob
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> ls
227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,39,107).
ftp: connect: Connection refused
```

Note that "alice" and "bob" are valid users on my server. So, the problem here is that when FTP goes passive to receive files, etc, it changes de IP to `(0,0,0,0,39,107)`, which is localhost in the server, even though I explicitly ask to use address `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.`

There is some material on the internet that relates this issue with NAT translation (which looks be the case), but I have tried their solutions.  Most of them ask us to set `pasv_address` (and sometimes port ranges), but none works.

Now, another weirdo:

```
listen_ipv6=NO
ssl_enable=YES
```

Now, I cannot even connect into the server, neither remote machine:

```
$ hostname
my_laptop

$ ftp XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
ftp: connect: Connection refused
```

nor localhost:

```
$ hostname
my_server

$ ftp localhost
ftp: connect: Connection refused
```

The latter makes sense since `list_address` points to the external IP address. But even I comment that line, still, I cannot connect.

It clear to me that the problem is in the addresses configuration since it looks to respond to IPv6 localhost. However, I am not an expert on such things, so I look for your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can connect to my vsftp server and `cd <some_dir>` OK.
But `ls` and `get foo.txt` failed with

```
ftp: connect: Connection refused
```

This is on a local LAN with no firewalls, no iptables.

The solution was to remove `pasv_address` from my `/etc/vsftp.conf` (and then restart vsftp)